# Inequality on Bessel function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, bessel-functions

Considering the Taylor expansion of the Bessel function of even order it seems like the following statements are true (I take $J_0$ as an example):

$1-\frac{x^2}{4}≤J_0(x)≤1$

$1 - \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^4}{64} - \frac{x^6}{2304}≤J_0(x)≤1 - \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^4}{64}$

Is there a general inequality saying that the Taylor series (around zero) of even order is smaller or equal $J_0$ is smaller or equal the Taylor series (around zero) of odd order? And if yes, is there a reference for that or how could one prove such a statement? Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I could figure out a way to prove it using integral representations of Bessel-functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's true only in a neighborhood of $0$.

Since you have a power series with alternating signs, you have an upper bound of the rest and more importantly for you here, the sign of the rest. See for example the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) on Wikipedia.

Of course, it's generally wrong on large intervals, since the polynomial curve may cross your function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this particular case, the estimates hold globally (which can be seen by using integral representations of Bessel functions instead of Taylor's theorem)...